# What does "leave somebody free to do something" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The context is as follows:

> MILLER: I see. But wait. I believe my problem is that I simply forgot a main tenet of my theory. The correlation can be established in my own case. I know that my soul and my body are intimately and consistently found together. From this one case I can generalize, at least as concerns life in this world, that sameness of body is a reliable sign of sameness of soul. This **leaves me free to** regard it as intelligible, in the case of death, that the link between the particular soul and the particular body it has been joined with is broken.
>
> -- from [a dialogue on personal identity and immortality](http://www.humanscience.org/docs/Perry%20%281978%29%20A%20Dialogue%20on%20Personal%20Identity%20and%20Immortality.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could substitute "allows me to," or "does not restrict me from [regarding]" if either of those are any clearer.

The idea behind "leaves me free" is that the preceding context doesn't prevent, discourage, or inhibit the action in question ("to regard"), and may even encourage or otherwise support the action.